# Need help in design principles to implement a wizard interface then checkout

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Well, I am trying to implement a wizard interface to help the user to choose the right service then add it to the shopping cart then possible checkout or discard.

This is similar to the concept of the t-mobile / att. Where we select the type of plan then the services we want ( minutes , data plan, mobile phone device then checkout) . The UI should be very web 2.0 like there would be help text , suggestions.. etc.

The technology is  asp.net 4.0 (mvp - codebehind model)

I did a lot of research, looked around using state design pattern , commander pattern.

My thinking is like a pattern where we have a Wizard controller which controls the wizard steps then once done hands over to the checkout process the end user can always go back and change any options during the wizard. Incase if its a existing customer then we have to skip few steps as we already few details.

Its all custom UI, I was thinking to use asp.net mutliview and each view loads based on current and next step.

In Brief I am confused and need some directions

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the multiview actually loads all details behind the scenes, one reason I don't like using it.

You could easily just have several ajax update panels. Each is the step of the wizard and when you post each item, you hide that panel and show the next step and potentially update and step indicator you have on your screen.

You have several choices - 
1. jQuery and ajax calls to load details into divs
2. update panels (as described above - my choice here)
3. wizard and multiviews - Im not a fan of using them. Certain customization issues exist with these built in controls at times and you need to be wary of certain details - like multiview actually processing all data for hidden items (if they contain queries this could significantly impact your system when you don't expect them to run and they do even though the view is hidden)

Comment: I will turn off the view state for all controls in the multi view and make sure to reload them, my onhly reason to use the multi view is to bind each them with a view and load them into multi-view dynamically

Comment: At this moment I am more focusing on the code behind and the business layer like controller,shopping cart and stuff , any suggestion their

Comment: thats a pretty open ended question : ) are you asking for code samples with MVP (are you actually using strict MVP, or just code behind and calling it mvp?)